# Reference request - Advanced Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am in need of a (linear?) algebra book that helps me understand my lectures better. The lectures are entirely proof-based, no applications, very few examples (so few that I often struggle because of the dense notation).

The topics for the second half are (the course is in German, where I am unsure of the direct translation I give the German descriptor):

groups, homogenous spaces, quotient groups, ideals and factor rings, divisors/factorization (?, in German it says "Teilbarkeit"), euklidian rings, integer factorization, modules, free modules, torsion, length of a module, matrices in euklidian rings, Struktursätze für Moduln (= theorems on the structure of modules?), minimal polynom, rational normal form, Smith-normal form, Jordan normal form, äußere Potenz (= Graßmann-Algebra?), bilinear forms, symmetric bilinear forms, eigenvectors and eigenvalues, tensor products, Charakter einer Darstellung (no clue how this translates!), conjugacy classes, Darstellungstheorie (= group representation?), orthogonality and its relations, division into irreducible representations

I believe that this half looks more like an intro to algebra course rather than just a linear algebra course but I believe we do not really dive deeper into the theory. The problem is that a deeper, intuitive understanding is hard to develop. For example, in the first half, we proofed a lot about determinants but the notes never really explained how one should think about determinants. The same pretty much applies to the second half of the course.

What I would like is a book that does not develop mentioned things much further but rather explains how one should think about those things. I cannot see the forest for the trees anymore. I can prove a couple of minute things but how they depend on each other eludes me and I would like to remedy that.

All the best!

Comment: Just to help with the translation: Character(s) of a representation, then representation theory, yes.

Comment: @TedShifrin I used wikipedia as a translation guide. Given that this course is just the second part of an intro to linear algebra, I tried to translate the German names into the most harmless options that wikipedia offered me (what I listed as Darstellungstheorie is probably more like the theory of group representations rather than full-blown represenataion theory).

Comment: Check out Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra.

Comment: Check out Artin's Algebra book. I recall that it contains most of the topics you mention, and it is a really good book with wealth of exercises.

Comment: I too come from a german-speaking undergraduate background, so I suppose we may have a similar experience. Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter 0 gives lots of intuition about algebraic objects, I think it also treats the tensor-algebra and the exterior algebra quite well. It does not however include much on representation theory, so you'd probably have to go to Artin or Lang for that.